SSLHandshakeException: Spring boot with Azure IDP in Docker
I have integrated Azure Idp with spring boot for single sign on, it works well in local or windows deployment as service, but throws SSL exception when deployed in docker, below is the application yml and security conf snippet.
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          azure:
            issuer-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<tenet id>>/v2.0
        registration:
          azure-dev:
            provider: azure
            client-id: <<client id>>
            client-secret: <<secret>>
            redirect-uri: https://>>system name>>:9443/app/login/oauth2/code/azure-dev
            scope:
              - openid
              - email
              - profile

Security config class
                .oauth2Login(oauthLogin -> oauthLogin
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.oidcUserService(getAuthUserService())))

My docker file looks like this
  FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-17-runtime:1.20-2.1719294801

USER root
# Install CA certificates and curl
#RUN microdnf update && microdnf install -y ca-certificates curl openssl

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p /app/java /app/config  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates\
    && chgrp -R root /app /app/config /app/java /usr/local/share/ca-certificates \
    && chmod -R 770 /app /app/config /usr/local/share/ca-certificates \
    && chmod -R 777 /app/java /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

COPY spring-security-azuread-3.2.1.jar /app/spring-security-azuread-3.2.1.jar

# Copy the concatenated certificate file into the container
COPY azure-idp-cert-chain.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-idp-cert-chain.pem

# Import the certificate chain into the Java truststore
RUN keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias ca-chain \
    -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/azure-idp-cert-chain.pem \
    -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

EXPOSE 9443
EXPOSE 8080

# Set a default command for debugging purposes
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/spring-security-azuread-3.2.1.jar"]

while running the image i am getting the error

[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to
retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST
request for
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/0ae51e19-07c8-4e4b-bb6d-648ee58410f4/oauth2/v2.0/token":
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target

JAVA_HOME is also set correctly, i also import DigiCertGlobalRootCA, DigiCertGlobalRootG2, MicrosoftECC2017 and MicrosoftRSA2017 certs, and also imported certs for login.microsoftonline.com, still getting the same issue.
In windows, i dint imported any certificate, it still works, but in redhat jdk/java it fails, any help/suggestion is appreciated

Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/v2.0" are you missing something here? Tenant Id should properly not be that place holder?

That i have added correctly, here while posting i just put placeholder

I am following this question. Please post the answer if you solve.
